# How to select non paying users?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select user without any orders OR without any 'PAID' orders :

```
SELECT "users".* 
FROM "users" 
LEFT OUTER JOIN orders ON orders.user_id=users.id 
WHERE (NOT (orders.state = 'paid'))
```

This will only return users with not yet paid orders and ignore users without orders.

How can I correct that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the logic:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM "users" u LEFT JOIN
     orders o
     ON o.user_id = u.id AND o.state = 'paid'  -- match on "paid"
WHERE o.user_id IS NULL;                       -- return without a match
```

This is probably better understood using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM "users" u 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1                    -- the following does not exist
                  FROM orders o
                  WHERE o.user_id = u.id AND  -- match on the user
                        o.state = 'paid'      -- match paid state
                 );
```

Comment: So the first one JOIN only the 'paid' orders, eliminating the irrelevant orders. Nice !